# C# checking if a clipboard contains duplicates efficiently

Tags: c#, windows-7

I have a code that copies 30 strings to a clipboard at a time from a data source that gets updated randomly; some times over a hundred new strings in under a second and some times there are no updates for a few minutes. I want to send all the strings over sockets to a database. What would be the most efficient approach to sending the strings over sockets with out sending duplicates?

Comment: Depends how they are stored. Care to elaborate?

Comment: Is bandwith a problem here? If not, why not let the database handle duplicates?

Comment: If the strings are very large you might try utilising Bloom filters to guarantee the set of strings that aren't duplicated then you can figure out the duplicates from the remaining strings that might be duplicated. But 100 strings per second x 100 unicode characters = 19kb/s which isn't all that much bandwidth...

Comment: @tomfanning i currently have them stored as an array of String

Comment: @BastiM bandwidth isn't a problem, but the database is already under very heavyload and I don't want to add to it

Comment: @pyCthon Do I get you right, that you want to check your clipboard for duplicates when you get new strings from your data source? Or would it be an option to just check for duplicates right before sending the strings to your db?

Comment: @BastiM both could be possible options

Comment: @pyCthon the most efficient way i can think of is eliminating the duplicates right before you send them - check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy but yet efficient way would be to check for and remove duplicates using LINQ right before you send your strings to the DB:

```
string[] original; //the array where all the string from your clipboard are in

string[] newStrings = original.Distinct().ToArray();
```

This way you eliminate all duplicate strings from `original`.